# How can I press the open application button in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, roblox

hi how to open the open roblox button with python and selenium

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from csv import DictReader
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
s = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
def main():
driver.get("https://roblox.com")

def get_cookies_values(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        dr = DictReader(f)
        list_dicts = list(dr)
    return list_dicts
    
cookies = get_cookies_values("roblox_cookies.csv")

for i in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(i)

driver.refresh()
time.sleep(1)
driver.get("https://web.roblox.com/games/537413528/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@id="game-details-play-button-container"]').click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: first edit question and use special functions (Ctrl+K) to format code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if using the selenium import is **NECESSARY**, as you never specified this, but you can use the

```py
import webbrowser
```

And if you have the position of the play button, use the pyautogui library

```py
import pyautogui
```

And then utilize the .open() function like this:

```py
webbrowser.open(wp)
pyautogui.click(x, y)
# wp is the webpage you want to open
# x and y should be the parameters of the button pos
```

Comment: @woraxe8641, no problem, if it did, press the check next to my answer so people can know this question was solved.